# Repeat component in React like *ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In React, we use `map` function inside JSX to iterate on items.

Is it possible to have a `Repeat` component like `*ngFor` in Angular?

```
<Repeat for={[1, 2, 3]}>
    ...
    <Repeat for={[5, 6, 7]}>
        ...
    </Repeat>
</Repeat>
```

If yes, Is it possible to have some contextual properties inside each `Repeat` component?

- `$item`  : the item in the array.
- `$index` : the index of the item in the collection.
- `$first` : is true if the item is the first item in the array.
- `$last`  : is true if the item is the last item in the array.

Is it possible to write such a component in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two approaches to write this:

1. Using [`React.cloneElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to clone children with additional props.
2. Using [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) to call `children` prop as a function.

### `React.clone()`

You can use `React.Children` to iterate over the children, and then clone each element with new props (shallow merged) using `React.cloneElement`.

```js
const Repeat = ({ for: items = [], children }) => {
  return items.map((item, index) => {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      // Checking isValidElement is the safe way and avoids a typescript
      // error too.
      if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          item,
          index,
          first: index === 0,
          last: index === items.length - 1
        });
      }
      return child;
    });

    return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>;
  });
};

const Span = ({ item, index, children }) => (
  <span>
    {children}, {item}
  </span>
);


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Clone</h1>
      <Repeat for={[1, 2, 3]}>
        <Span>Outer</Span>
        <Repeat for={[4, 5, 6]}>
          <Span>Inner</Span>
        </Repeat>
      </Repeat>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### Render Props

You can pass props to `children` with render props. In this approach, the `children` prop is a function which can accept any arguments you want to pass and returns the children:

```js
const Repeat = ({ for: items = [], children }) => {
  return items.map((item, index) => {
    return children({
      item,
      index,
      first: index === 0,
      last: index === items.length - 1
    });
  });
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Render Props</h1>
      <Repeat for={[1, 2, 3]}>
        {({ item, index }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div>Outer, {item}</div>
            <Repeat for={[4, 5, 6]}>
              {({ item, index }) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <div>Inner, {item}</div>
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
            </Repeat>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </Repeat>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

#### Original Answer:

Yes.

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Repeat = ({ for: items = [], children }) => {
  return items.map((item, index) => {
    return React.cloneElement(children, {
      item,
      index,
      first: index === 0,
      last: index === items.length - 1
    });
  });
};
```

I use `React.cloneElement` to pass props to children. There are other techniques as well if you don't like this one. As this one has a limitation that `<Repeat>` can have only one child element

Usage:

```
import { Repeat } from './Repeat';

function Child({ item, index, first, last }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Item: {item}</span>
      <span>, Index: {index}</span>
      <span>, First: {String(first)}</span>
      <span>, Last: {String(last)}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Repeat for={[1, 2, 3]}>
        <Child />
      </Repeat>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What about this use case? `<Repeat for={[1, 2, 3]}> <span>{index}</span> </Repeat>`
I don't want to write a `<Child>` component every time.

Comment: I don't think so..Instead of creating a explicit `<Child>` component, [the example here shows how to inline the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#functions-as-children).

Comment: Is it possible to support nested repeat too? (you mentioned about other techniques)

Comment: Yes it is. Updated answer

Comment: I got an error in Typescript: 'Repeat' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'any[]' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2786)

Comment: You may want to open another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would you need something like this but maybe `useContext` can come and help. Here's a quick [codesandbox with this approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bas-tewcd)

Comment: Is it possible to use like this? `<Repeat for={[1, 2, 3]}> {(index) => <div key={index}>This is item {index} in the list</div>}<Repeat for={[4, 5, 6]}>{(index) => <div key={index}>This is item {index} in the list</div>}</Repeat></Repeat>`, without any explicit component inside it.